# Makefile: add prefix to nothing

Tags: bash, makefile

In Bash, brace expansion just works:

```
$ echo client_win{,_throttle,_freq}.exe
client_win.exe client_win_throttle.exe client_win_freq.exe
```

In Makefile:

```
$(addsuffix .exe,client_win $(addprefix client_win, _throttle _freq )):client_win.c def.h
client_win.exe:
    $(CC_W)                -o $@ $< -lws2_32
client_win_throttle.exe:
    $(CC_W_REL) -DTHROTTLE -o $@ $< -lws2_32
client_win_freq.exe:
    $(CC_W_REL) -DFREQ     -o $@ $< -lws2_32
```

Is it possible to have `client_win` itself absorbed into `$(addprefix client_win,...)`?

Something like this?

```
$(addprefix client_win, NOTHING _throttle _freq )
```

Comment: `client_win\.exe` is not the same as `client_win.exe`, although they may appear the same when echoed. Do not use `addprefix` in this dangerous way.

Comment: Just discovered that when `make <tab> <tab>` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy because make, unlike the shell, has no concept of "existing but zero length string".  Make will expand something and look at the resulting string and if it contains no characters it's as if it didn't exist at all.

You could do something like this:

```
$(patsubst %,client_%.exe, win win_throttle win_freq)
```

To remove the "empty" option by adding more to it.

Or you can just write the "empty" one out:

```
client-win.exe $(patsubst %,client_win_%.exe, throttle freq)
```